# Why can't I just add Content-Type:text/html to a text file when Python can?

Tags: python, html, http-headers

This will seem like a stupid question to most of you but why can't I do this:

```
Content-Type:text/html

<html>
<head><title>Hello</title></head>
<body>
<h1>Hello, World!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

in a file called `test.txt` and open it in my browser as html when a Python script can do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print '<html>'
print '<head>'
print '<title>Hello Word - First CGI Program</title>'
print '</head>'
print '<body>'
print '<h2>Hello Word! This is my first CGI program</h2>'
print '</body>'
print '</html>'
```

and everything works fine. I can't see any difference, they are both printing `Content-Type:text/html` at the top of the information the browser has requested.

Comment: The second one is a server side CGI script? what framework are you using?

Comment: I'm not using any framework. This is purely for my own curiosity, I've never really grokked how headers actually work.

Comment: You can if you can persuade your browser to access the filesystem over `http` instead of `file`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An HTTP response consists of headers and body, separate by the first `\r\n\r\n` received. By the time a web server sends an ordinary file, it has already sent all the headers, and the separator.
When a script is run, however, the headers are not sent automatically.

So in the first case, your webserver guessed the content-type from the extension, and sent appropriate headers, before sending the contents of the file. In the second the script sent an overriding header for the content-type. It's then up to the web-server how it handles this, in terms of inserting the other standard http headers.

EDIT:
Apache use mod_mine and /etc/mime.types to map file extensions to Content-Types. It probably defaults to text/plain for anything that doesn't have an extension it understands.

The browser probably works off the extension only if it doesn't have a Content-Type to use.

Plain files are assumed to just contain the data, and the headers are generated by the web server, whereas cgi scripts are expected/allowed to generate their own headers.

Comment: When would a browser _not_ guess the content type from the extension? I tried no extension at all but it still interpreted it as a text file. Are the rules on how to treat certain files specified in the httpd.conf file?

Comment: Tell us more about how your web server is set up and how you are testing it.

Comment: I'm using cpanel on a shared hosting account. I don't have access to httpd.conf. There's nothing special in my .htaccess file. I'm testing by uploading the file as you see it in my question to both the root of my server and the /cgi-bin/ Bare in mind I'm not really trying to achieve anything, it's purely for my own curiosity and to better my understanding of servers/headers etc...

Comment: Thank you, I have no further questions your honor.

Answer (score 3):

When browsers read directly from a file, they aren't looking for http headers.  When a python script is answering a browser's http request, that is different, and the browser expects the first lines to be http headers which it then interprets as you would expect.

Comment: How does the browser decide whether to look for headers or not? Does it go off extension?

Comment: @MrMisterMan There will be configuration which tells the server whether to run the file as a script, or just serve it as data. This can be the directory it's in, or the file extension. And it is the server machine that decides what the Content-Type is, not the browser.